# Installing Aspell on Windows using emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, aspell

I'm using Emacs23.3 on Windows7 and I tried to install Aspell. Installation worked, but when I tried to install the English dictionary I got: 
"The extended atributes are inconsistent." (I have no problems installing all sorts of other programs). 
Right now I can't work with a dictionary and when I type at the Emacs: "alt-x aspell" it says: "no match".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Emacs and might be more suited to superuser. Which version of Windows are you running? I've just installed the latest version of Aspell and the English dictionary using the binaries from http://aspell.net/win32/ on Windows 7 Professional (64-bit) and they seem to work fine.